# Why my azure web app receives all requests as GET?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am currently having a problem with my azure web app, when I send a postman requests only GET methods work, I checked the logs of my web app, and for some reason it converts all my requests to GET. I am using a default settings for Azure web app.
Here how I send the post request:
**url: mecosapi20230710115011.azurewebsites.net/media;
header: Content-type application/json;
body row json:**

```
{
  "Title": "Test presentation",
  "IsAdult": false,
  "StartYear": 2022,
  "EndYear": null,
  "RuntimeMinutes": 120,
  "Genres": "Action, Drama, coMedy",
  "AvgRating": 7.8,
  "NumVotes": 1000,
  "AssociatedPeople": "1, 2, 3, 4"
}
```

P.S: Methods are written correctly, I've tested all of them both locally and deployed

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: @DasariKamali My bad, already fixed it, I had to send https for some reason, but http worked for Get idk

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ruby, adding "https://" in url is fixing my issue